# How to sync two MySQL high load tables with 10M rows?

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb, clustering

I have two identical MySQL innodb table with 10M rows each. One is used at backend while other at application end. Thus, either of them loaded. I need to synchronize them in a way which is fast and non blocking. How can I do that?

Is there any particular LINUX software for this?

And how about syncing two dbs?

**EDIT**

Both tables exist on different dbs hosted on different machines. And both of them are updated separately before the sync process.

Comment: Are the two tables in separate databases, are the databases on different servers? What is the purpose of separating the two tables? Are updates made to both tables or only one of the tables?

Comment: Both tables exist on different dbs hosted on different machines. And both of them are updated separately before the sync process.

Comment: Is it the same database on two machines or are there major differences between the two databases?

Comment: how should conflicts be handled, e.g. a row was updated on both servers in a different way, a row updated on one server is deleted on the other server, on both servers different rows are inserted with the same primary key? Are there references to other tables?

Comment: @ssmusoke: different machines

Comment: @miracle173: yes tables are related to each other, I would like to know the conflict if any occurs so that we can find a way out :)

Comment: Are there major differences between the two databases, or is it the same database on two different machines?

Comment: database 'x' on machine 'a' while database 'y' on machine 'b'

Comment: is database 'x' a copy of database 'y' or vice versa?

Comment: y is a copy of x which is operated separately..

Answer (score 1):

pt-table-sync from [Percona Toolkit](http://www.percona.com/software/percona-toolkit/) will do this sort of thing.